# LibGDX: Add justTouched() in specific rectangle

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm using this code : https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game

But I would like to change the way that the raindrop disappear. I want it disappear when i touch it.

So I added this:

```
if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
  if (Gdx.input.getX() > raindrop.getX() &&
      Gdx.input.getX() < (raindrop.getX() + raindrop.getWidth()) &&
      Gdx.input.getY() > raindrop.getY() &&
      Gdx.input.getY() < (raindrop.getY() + raindrop.getHeight())) {
     dropSound.play();
     iter.remove();
  }
}
```

but it's not working well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `camera.unproject(Vector)` to transform your screen coordinates from a click or touch to your gameworld. This is needed because the origin is not necessarily the same and using the camera you can also zoom in and out, move around, rotate and so on. Unprojecting will take care of all of that and give you your game world coordinate matching the pointers position.

```
if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
    Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
    touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
    camera.unproject(touchPos);
    if (raindrop.contains(touchPos.x,touchPos.y)) {
        dropSound.play();
        iter.remove();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is get the bounding rectangle for the sprite, and check if your mouse is within the rectangle, the following code could help

```
if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
     if (raindrop.getBoundingRectangle().contains(Gdx.input.getX, Gdx.input.getY()) {
        dropSound.play();
        iter.remove();
     }
}
```